# jQuery Hide/Show Failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I am building a SPA with with with jQuery with Semantic & Bootstrap for UI. Currently I am facing a problem where jQuery is failing to hide and show 2 elements of the same level, but everywhere else it's working. When the Hide-this-Show-that lines are executing I can see the DOM change when I inspect the element, but on display, the page just flickers. I thought at first that maybe it was refreshing, but after close inspection, it seems it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```js
//JQUERY BELOW
$.post(BaseURL + "account/login.php?param1=user&param2=pass", (response) => {
  if (response == something) {
    $("#login_view").hide();
    $("#main_view").show();
  } else {
    // SOMETHING ELSE
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div id="login_view">
          <!-- STUFF HERE -->
        </div>

        <div id="main_view">
          <!-- OTHER STAFF HERE -->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Considering that in other parts of the app, the Hide/Show subroutines are working, I thought this code is that straight forward. When I add a console.log after the two hide/show calls, it prints out just fine. The main_page id already set to display:none in CSS as the page loads

Comment: You have no issue with show/hide. Indeed you have issue with the ajax or the login process.

Comment: My ajax request is returning the data that I expected depending on the params I provided.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and the snippet to include enough CSS so that it recreates the issue (a [mre]). Please also show how your JavaScript code is getting called. Be sure to click Run code snippet before posting to ensure there are no errors other than the ones you have in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add `display: none` to #main_view in order to hide it first, then as soon as the response returned, hide the login and show main via jQuery.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#login_view").hide();
  $("#main_view").show();
}, 2000);
```

```css
#login_view{
  display: block;
}
#main_view{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="pusher">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div id="login_view">
                   <h1>Login</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="main_view">
                    <h1>Main</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just need to add display none to #main_view in order to hide it first, then as soon as the response returned, hide the login and show main via jQuery.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this answer solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

i've cracked this one. The problem was with Semantic UI transitions. There are similar issues also on Git of elements not being able to change if you use transitions to show or hide elements. I just changed changed the code from:

```
$("#login_page").hide().transition("fade out");
$("#main_page").show().transition("fade in");
```

to

```
$("#login_page").hide();
$("#main_page").show();
```

Thanx for the support.